# MYSQL JSON search returns results in square brackets

Tags: mysql, mysql-json

I am conducting a simple search of JSON held in a MySQL database, however the results are returning enclosed in square brackets and quotes.

```
SELECT stored_json->>'$.*.referal' AS referal FROM table WHERE id =  100
```

results in

```
+------------+
| referal    |
+------------+
| ["search"] |
+------------+
```

Is there a way to get MYSQL to return the results without the brackets and quotes?

```
+------------+
| referal    |
+------------+
| search     |
+------------+
```

Thanks

*****Edit*****

JSON example

```
{
    "100": {
            "referal": "search"
    }
}
```

Comment: Your JSON path returns an array from your JSON document.  It happens to hold only one value, but it is an array nonetheless.  [Edit] your question to show us the document in question (the value of your `stored_json` column) and we may be able to help you change the path to extract the first array element.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you just want a single value from the array, then extract that value and unquote it:

```
SELECT JSON_UNQUOTE(JSON_EXTRACT(
    JSON_EXTRACT(stored_json, '$.*.referal'), '$[0]')) AS referal
FROM ...

+---------+
| referal |
+---------+
| search  |
+---------+
```

The JSON_UNQUOTE() function converts the result to a string, but if you give it a JSON array or object, it can't remove the brackets and double-quotes. Those just become part of the string. You must extract a single scalar value from the JSON, and then you can use JSON_UNQUOTE() to remove the double-quotes.

I suppose you might want to get results if there are more than one value in your JSON document.

```
+----------------------------+
| referal                    |
+----------------------------+
| ["search","word of mouth"] |
+----------------------------+
```

Sorry, I don't see a solution for this, other than:

```
REPLACE(..., '[', '')
```

And so on, removing the other characters you don't want.

In MySQL 8.0, the function REGEXP_REPLACE() can strip multiple characters in one pass:

```
REGEXP_REPLACE(..., '["\\[\\]]', '')
```

Comment: Great, thanks. For neatness I adjusted this a little to use  stored_json->>'$.*.referal' instead of JSON_EXTRACT(stored_json, '$.*.referal') but essentially the same.