# mySQL json array reformatting

Tags: mysql, mysql-json

I have a table which contains a column "owners", which has json data in it like this:

```
[
   {
      "first":"bob",
      "last":"boblast"
   },
   {
      "first":"mary",
      "last": "marylast"
   }
]
```

I would like to write a query that would return for each row that contains data like this, a column that has all of the first names concatenated with a comma.

i.e.

```
id                owners
----------------------------
1                 bob,mary
2                 frank,tom
```

Not on mysql 8.0 yet.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the values as a JSON array:

```
SELECT JSON_EXTRACT(owners, '$[*].first') AS owners ...
```

But that returns in JSON array format:

```
+-----------------+
| owners          |
+-----------------+
| ["bob", "mary"] |
+-----------------+
```

JSON_UNQUOTE() won't take the brackets and double-quotes out of that. You'd have to use REPLACE() as I show in a recent answer here:

[MYSQL JSON search returns results in square brackets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69738299/mysql-json-search-returns-results-in-square-brackets/69738858#69738858)

You should think about *not* storing data in JSON format if it doesn't support the way you need to query them.

Comment: We dont necessarily need to query the data. We considered adding additional tables, but when we switch to mysql 8, all these issues go away with JSON_TABLE, which will allow us to use GROUP_CONCAT.

Comment: Is JSON_UNQUOTE only MariaDB?

Comment: @bpeikes I will leave it to you to look it up in the JSON function reference in MySQL.

Comment: Odd, when I first searched for JSON_UNQUOTE, I only saw refrences to MariaDB, I see it now in the mysql docs.

Answer (score 0):

Here is another option, get a helper table with running numbers up to the max json array length, and extract values by individual index, after that `group_concat` the values, something like this:

```
SELECT g.id, GROUP_CONCAT(g.name)
FROM (
    SELECT a.id, JSON_UNQUOTE(JSON_EXTRACT(a.owners, CONCAT('$[', n.idx, '].first'))) name
    FROM running_numbers n
    JOIN mytable a
) g
GROUP BY g.id
```

https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=d7453c9edf89f79ca4ab2f63578b320c